# sendEmail(email, subject, body, object) issue: adding html object removes message

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Simply put, the issue I'm having is when I add the object to the sendEmail() function I lose the message body and subject. What could be causing this?

```
const subject = "Semi-Monthly Projections Reminder";
const firstBody = "Hello Team!\n\nPlease be advised, your Projections are due on the 7th!";
const secondBody = "Hello Team!\n\nPlease be advised, your Projections are due on the 22nd!";
const emails = ["testemail@gmail.com"];
const signature =
'<b style="color:rgb(34,34,34)"><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif">April Stephenson</span></b>'
'<b style="color:rgb(34,34,34)"><span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif"><br></span></b>'
'<font color="#222222" face="Arial, sans-serif" style=""><span style="font-size:12.6667px">Administrative Assistant</span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt"> - Dry Utilities</span></font>'
'<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34)"><span style="font-size:9.5pt"> <img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/bOR5KWbalQbNZWNqfOQzqjMrnnvtg-h5OCXmwApmWlftTUqc9Uq6rR5etaxXt821ZIefMQRtdFAKx3Ch1GEiyHXOCNlfUHiYpbXN6hQ8h-t8hbiXfrh9J8wDKwY5aqEvcQ3WILQygjBUoCs2T25j8V8lgoRcMjOxXw9Jh45QI2zd9S00OtUasAe5DDjdiQ_OpO68E6FUYxTL6i0jBQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=11GllWPsJpOmvC1bTYnEbi33T8DvfhNAi&amp;revid=0BzT9ddH4Y2R1Znc4eVY5UXlzUmhDaU9idEVLNGpMYWFmK3BnPQ"></span>'
'<span style="color:rgb(34,34,34)"><span style="font-size:9.5pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=1151+Duryea+Ave%2C+Irvine%2C+CA+92614&amp;oq=1151+Duryea+Ave%2C+Irvine%2C+CA+92614&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57.272j0j4&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)" target="_blank"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif">1151 Duryea Ave, Irvine, CA 92614</span></a></span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif"><br>Office: </span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:rgb(17,85,204)"><a href="tel:(949)988-3270" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)"target="_blank">(949) 333-</a><u>5408</u></span></span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:blue"><br></span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt"><a href="http://www.murowdc.com/" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)" target="_blank"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif">www.murowdc.com</span></a></span>'
'<span style="font-size:9.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif"> |<span style="color:blue"> </span><span style="color:rgb(17,85,204)"><a href="mailto:astephenson@murowdc.com" style="color:rgb(17,85,204)" target="_blank">astephenson@murowdc.com</a></span></span>'


function sendEmails_7th(){
  for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject, firstBody, {htmlBody: signature}); 
  }
}

function sendEmails_22nd() {
  for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[i], subject, secondBody, {htmlBody: signature});
  }
```

Comment: The subject should not be affected by adding the object. When including the object the "body" will be shown only for email clients not supporting HTML. By the way, the last edit missing the concatenation operators to put together the signature strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.  I do loose the message body because it gets replaced with the htmlBody

```
const subject = "Semi-Monthly Projections Reminder";
const firstBody = "Hello Team!\n\nPlease be advised, your Projections are due on the 7th!";
const secondBody = "Hello Team!\n\nPlease be advised, your Projections are due on the 22nd!";
const emails = ["email"];
const signature ='<h1>Hello world</h1>';

function sendEmails_7th(){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[0], subject, firstBody, {htmlBody: signature}); 
}
```

Comment: Oooohhhhhhh So I have to add the body and the signature together as an HTML string. thank you!